Ошибка в кодировке при прочтении pdf файла
При прочтении pdf-файла возникает следующая ошибка:

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 256: invalid continuation byte

вот мой код:
df_pdf = tabula.read_pdf(r'C:\Users\Пользователь\Downloads\kcp-mag-2021 v2.pdf')

С чем это может быть связано? У моих коллег с тем же кодом все корректно работает. Может ли это быть связано с анаконда навигатором (Джава установлена как следует)?

У моих коллег с тем же кодом все корректно работает. => с тем же pdf ?

Операционки у вас и у коллег одинаковые? Дефолтная кодировка может быть разная в системе.

Ошибка

`utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 256: invalid continuation byte

возникает, когда происходит попытка декодирования байтового объекта с использованием неправильной кодировки.
df_pdf = tabula.read_pdf(r'C:\Users\Пользователь\Downloads\kcp-mag-2021 v2.pdf', encoding='latin1')

Попробуйте явно указать кодировку (которая Вам необходима).

Скорее всего там cp1251 кодировка должна быть.

можно еще latin-1 попробовать
